# Rewriting a property named "default" with Google Closure Templates

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-templates

In the data that I send to a Google Closure template, I have a property named `default`. I plan on compiling both the JavaScript code and the code generated by SoyToJsSrcCompiler using the Google Closure Compiler. But the problem is that the generated code from the template prevents the compiler from renaming the `default` property.

This is the template code:

```
/**
 * @param test
 */
{template .template}
    <div>{$test.a.b.default.c.d}</div>
{/template}
```

And this is the generated code:

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, *>=} opt_data
 * @param {(null|undefined)=} opt_ignored
 * @return {string}
 * @notypecheck
 */
test.template = function(opt_data, opt_ignored) {
  return '<div>' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.test.a.b['default'].c.d) + '</div>';
};
```

Is there any way I can get:

```
opt_data.test.a.b.default.c.d
```

intead of:

```
opt_data.test.a.b['default'].c.d
```

or any other way in which I can keep my property named `default`?

Right now, the compiler renames the `default` property in my JavaScript code, but doesn't rename it in the code generated by SoyToJsSrcCompiler, because this code uses the quoted version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't currently seem to be any supported way of doing this. I changed the name of the property from `default` to something else that gets renamed properly.

Answer (score 1):

`default` is a semi reserved word in JavaScript. It is used in `switch case` statements:

```
switch ( variable ) {
    case a:
        break;
    case b:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

It it perfectly safe to in object traveling but not as scope level variable:

```
object.some.thing.else.default;
```

Consider this object tree:

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: {
            "1": {
                "default": 2
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

You can get the value (`2`) by saying:

```
a.b.c[1].default // 2
```

But also:

```
a["b"]["c"]["1"]["default"] // 2
```

JSHint throws a warning for quoting object traveling for non qoute needed situations. In this case `["b"]`, `["c"]`, `["default"]`.

Comment: That's true, but it is still perfectly valid syntax if it is used as a key. `a.default` is valid, as is `{default: 1}`. If SoyToJsSrcCompiler would write it using the dot syntax, or if the Closure Compiler would not rename it from `default` to something else, then the compiled code should work correctly...

Comment: @rid just updated. What I'm trying to say is that the key is not renamed but just quoted. Nothing will happen in the JavaScript

Comment: I'm referring here to the Closure Compiler. The tool renames almost all the keys that are not in quotes. My code contains the key without quotes. The generated code contains the key with quotes. Therefore the compiled code will contain a renamed property (mine, the one without quotes) and a non-renamed property (the generated one, with quotes), which in the end will not work, because one part of the code refers to the renamed property while the other part refers to the non-renamed property. So I'm looking for a solution for this, that does not require using a name different from `default`.

Comment: This is probably do to the fact that in ecmascript 3, it is NOT perfectly valid - although browsers allowed it. In ecmascript 5, it is allowed. I recommend filing an issue with the closure-templates project as this seems like it should be addressed. https://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/issues/list

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, I also used `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT` to let the compiler know that it should tread the source as strict ECMAScript 5. Is `default` still not allowed in strict ECMAScript 5?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, ...but of course, that wouldn't matter, because the generated template code has nothing to do with the compiler when it gets generated... It would only matter if the generator would have an option to know what version of ECMAScript to target. Which makes me wonder what happens if I compile the JavaScript code in ECMAScript 3 mode. Checking.

Comment: My guess is that Closure-templates needs updated to support ecmascript 5 property names.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, tested now. The compiler, in ECMAScript 3 mode, issues an error. In 5, if not using advanced optimizations, it quotes `default`. In 5, with advanced optimizations, it renames `default`. I see that it doesn't rename something like `id` or `filters` though... It should probably just leave `default` as it is as well...